# An error with... operator precedence?? (.Net Compact Framework)

Tags: math, compact-framework

I have this operation:

```
t = (x - (y * (z + w)) - w) / 2;
```

where:

x = 268;
y = 4;
z = 20;
w = 30;

As far as I know the result will be 49, but I getting 19.

Where is my error? (In using this code on a .Net Compact Framework 2.0 SP2 WinForm app).

Thank you.

Comment: how do you figure 49 ?   19 is the right value...

Comment: This is what I want: t = (x - (y * (z + w) - w)) / 2;

Comment: You had placed parenthesis where it was nt necessary ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want

```
 t = (x -(y * (z+w) - w))/2
```

which *is* 49

Comment: Beat me to it, but I like that you removed the unnecessary parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You should get 19...

```
t = (x - (y * (z + w)) - w) / 2;
t = (268 - (4 * (20 + 30)) - 30) / 2;  
t = (268 - (4 * (50)) - 30) / 2;  
t = (268 - (200) - 30) / 2;  
t = (68 - 30) / 2;  
t = (38) / 2;  
t = 19;
```

I suspect your error was at this step:

```
t = (268 - (200) - 30) / 2;
```

If you did 200 - 30 in your head you would get 170.  And then 268 - 170 = 98 and 98 / 2 = 49.
Because you have -200 and -30, you need to combine those to -230 not -170.

Answer (score 0):

t = (268 - (200) - 30) / 2

t = 38 / 2

t = 19

19 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check your math again - either you've made a mistake in a calculation or your understanding of operator precedence is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
t = (x - ((y * (z + w)) - w)) / 2;
```